# UILabel showing wrong

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

i'm using a tableview to load datas from my college db, the table load the tablecell normally... but when i scroll down the table the name of the discipline goes well but the grade is showing up one on top of above

[image: Screenshot]

why is that?

```
#import "NFMainViewController.h"
#import "NFData.h"

@interface NFMainViewController ()

@end

@implementation NFMainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        data = [[NFData getData] objectForKey:@"data"];
        cursoData = nil;
        cursosView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [cursosView setTitle:@"Cursos"];
        cursosTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        [cursosTable setDelegate:self];
        [cursosTable setDataSource:self];
        [cursosView.view addSubview:cursosTable];
        [self pushViewController:cursosView animated:NO];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - TableView delegates

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == cursosTable) {
        return [data count];
    } else {
        return [cursoData count];
    }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *ident = @"headerIdent";
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *view = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:ident];
    if (view == nil) {
        view = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] initWithReuseIdentifier:ident];
    }
    if (tableView == cursosTable) {
        view.textLabel.text = [[data objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"unidade"];
    } else {
        NSDictionary *temp = [cursoData objectAtIndex:section];
        view.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@º/%@", [temp objectForKey:@"semestre"], [temp objectForKey:@"ano"]];
    }
    return view;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == cursosTable) {
        return [[[data objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"cursos"] count];
    } else {
        return [[[cursoData objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"disciplinas"] count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *ident = @"cellIdent";
    UITableViewCell *view = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ident];
    if (view == nil) {
        view = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ident];
    }
    if (tableView == cursosTable) {
        view.textLabel.text = [[[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"cursos"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"curso"];
    } else {

        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:10.0f];

        view.textLabel.font = font;
        view.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        NSDictionary *temp = [[[cursoData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"disciplinas"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        view.textLabel.text = [temp objectForKey:@"disciplina"];

        CGRect notaRect = view.bounds;
        notaRect.origin.x = notaRect.size.width - 70.0f;
        notaRect.size.width = 50.0f;
        UILabel *nota = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:notaRect];
        nota.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        nota.font = font;
        nota.text = [temp objectForKey:@"nota"];
        [view addSubview:nota];

        CGRect labelRect = view.textLabel.frame;
        labelRect.size.height -= 60;
        view.textLabel.frame = labelRect;

        CGRect progRect = view.bounds;
        progRect.origin.x += 6.0f;
        progRect.size.width -= 12.0f;
        progRect.origin.y += progRect.size.height - 6.0f;
        progRect.size.height = 5.0f;
        UIProgressView *prog = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithFrame:progRect];
        int faltas = [[temp objectForKey:@"faltas"] intValue];
        int maximo = [[temp objectForKey:@"maximo"] intValue];
        float value = 1.0f * faltas / maximo;
        if (value > 1.0f) {
            prog.progressTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        } else if (value == 1.0f) {
            prog.progressTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        } else if (value >= 0.7f) {
            prog.progressTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        }
        [prog setProgress:value];
        [view addSubview:prog];
    }
    return view;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == cursosTable) {
        cursoData = [[[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"cursos"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"epocas"];
        notasView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        [notasView setTitle:@"Disciplinas"];
        notasTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        [notasTable setDelegate:self];
        [notasTable setDataSource:self];
        [notasView.view addSubview:notasTable];
        [self pushViewController:notasView animated:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nota `UILabel` is created each time a `UITableViewCell` is dequeued. So the first time the tableview loads everything is fine. Then when you start scrolling, your code reuse cells with the nota label already created, but you add another label on top of it. You need to reuse the label previously created.

The best way is to create a `UITableViewCell` subclass with a nota property for instance.

Comment: But why is that happening just on the nota UILabel? The same doesn`t happens with the first label nor the progress

Comment: For the first label you're using the default UITableViewCell label, so you are not re creating it each time. For the progress, my guess is that they are stacked on each other, so the previous ones are hidden.